# Extended User Model migrate

Tags: python, django

I want to extend my user model to hold a profile picture. 
I am aware that you can create a new model and link it with foreign keys but since every type of user in my application has a Picture i figured i could add it to the user itself.

I extended the user in models.py:

```
class ExtendedUser(AbstractUser):
      user_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=housemate_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then i registered the model with the admin:

```
admin.site.register(ExtendedUser, UserAdmin)
```

And set my settings.py to:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'houses.ExtendedUser'
```

When i migrate i get:

```
 houses.extendeduser (referred to by fields: account.EmailAddress.user, admin.LogEntry.user)
```

I assume it has something to with circular dependencies mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) and Django is proposing to create two migrations for this, but I don't understand how to go about it, can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: It's not very clear what the problem is. Is that the entire error message you get? Note that you can't change `AUTH_USER_MODEL` after you have ran `migrate` for the first time (see the warning in the docs you linked to).

Comment: Yes it is, and the warning i linked to also says that its possible to change it I do the migration in two steps no? (If you see this error, you should break the loop by moving the models depended on by your User model into a second migration)

Comment: The note about creating a second migration is in the other warning block. I was referring to: *Changing [the AUTH_USER_MODEL] setting after you have tables created is not supported by makemigrations*. If you haven't ran migrate, then the warning doesn't apply.